# Find the largest cluster of points within one kilometer

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial

I ran into a problem in Postgres when I was working with spatial dates. I have a table with columns: object id and its coordinates (latitude and longitude, data type is geometry). I need to find the largest cluster of points within one kilometer. How could I do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "largest cluster"? Anyway, I found this article very useful when trying to find all points within a certain radius of a point http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Comment: Thank you! I mean area which ise qual to 1 km, where there are most points.

Comment: Interesting question! So, basically "where do I put a 1KM area circle to cover the most points?". I would try to simplify... Make a grid of small hexagons. Count the number of points per hexagon. Now build 1km-sized larger hexes from the small ones and sum up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) to create a cluster with a given distance and minimal number of points. In the query bellow I create clusters of points within 1000 meters with a minimal number of two points, and in the outer query I count them:

```
SELECT 
  cluster,count(*),ST_Union(geom)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    geom,
    ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom,1000,2) OVER () AS cluster FROM t) j
WHERE cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

**Note**: `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` expects the distance in the unit of the underlying SRS! As I'm using [`EPSG:26986`](https://epsg.io/26986), it is metres. Adjust this parameter to your SRS. Also note that `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` (**PostgreSQL 13+**) enables you to fetch the first results from the `ORDER BY` clause in case they share the same value. In other words, in case two or more clusters contain the same amount of points, they will all be listed. If you use `LIMIT 1` or `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` you will get just one (*arbitrary*) record.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2006efff8083c30eeaabe8982f2b9b33)

```
CREATE TABLE t (geom geometry(point,26986));
-- 100 random points over the given polygon
INSERT INTO t 
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints('SRID=26986;POLYGON((4216635.436744224 3906228.6933973604,4225112.992686871 3914713.9388259286,4237223.322966506 3902640.089526773,4228720.260658542 3894129.3145975843,4216635.436744224 3906228.6933973604))',100,42))).geom;
```

[image]

Select the biggest cluster (with ties) with at least 2 points within a distance of 1km from each other.

```
SELECT count(*),ST_Union(geom)
FROM (
  SELECT geom, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom,1000,2) OVER () AS cluster 
  FROM t) j
WHERE cluster IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster
ORDER BY 1 DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

 count |                                                                                                                                        st_union                                                                                                                                        
-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     6 | 01040000206A690000060000000101000000DEF0FA99831C5041605685812CC14D410101000000949040228D1C50418B6D583ACCC24D4101010000008441B6498F1C50414E04C49555C44D41010100000020AD7813131D50410179F7E239C24D41010100000015A4562E231D5041B07FE58158C04D4101010000009F78C907301D50414A726F118CC44D41
```

If we overlay the minimum bounding circle of this result set with the original data set we can better visualize the cluster area (**for illustration only**):

```
WITH i AS (
  SELECT count(*),ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_Union(geom)) AS geom
  FROM (
    SELECT geom, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom,1000,2) OVER () AS cluster 
    FROM t) j
  WHERE cluster IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY cluster
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
)
SELECT geom FROM i
UNION 
SELECT geom FROM t
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [`ST_MinimumBoundingCircle`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html)
- [`ST_GeneratePoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html)